# Copy sdf table from one database to another in C# with sql ce

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

New to sqlce. I've spent two days trying to figure to this out and searching stackoverflow for similar questions. 
How do I utilize sqlce to copy a table (schema and data only) from one sdf database to another sdf database? What sqlce key terms should I be looking for?  Any advice is appreciated, any code more so.

Comment: You may have to use the CREATE query of the table to have it in the target DB. Similarly a loop in the source table to copy the records into the target DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with: requires sql server compact nuget

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ConsoleApp5 {
  class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
      string tableName = "ZTVC_MF_S_VALCHA";
      string sourceString = "Data Source = C:\\Users\\David\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp5\\ConsoleApp5\\bin\\Debug\\XXX.sdf";
      string destString = "Data Source = C:\\Users\\David\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp5\\ConsoleApp5\\bin\\Debug\\YYY.sdf";

      using ( SqlCeConnection sourceConn = new SqlCeConnection() ) {
        SqlCeCommand sourceCmd = sourceConn.CreateCommand();
        sourceCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sourceCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "tableName", tableName );
        sourceConn.ConnectionString = sourceString;
        sourceConn.Open();

        using ( SqlCeConnection destConn = new SqlCeConnection() ) {
          destConn.ConnectionString = destString;
          destConn.Open();

          DoesTableExist( tableName, destConn );
          DataTable dt=GetDataFromTable( tableName, sourceConn );
          CopyTableSchema( tableName, dt, destConn );
          FillTableCopy( tableName, dt, destConn );
          DeleteTable( tableName, destConn );
          Console.ReadKey();
        }

      }
    }
    private static void FillTableCopy(  string tabName, DataTable dt, SqlCeConnection destConn) {
        List<string> dTypesList = new List<string>();
        int dTypesListIndexCounter = 0;
        string sqlCmd = "";
        foreach ( DataRow row in dt.Rows ) {
          sqlCmd = "INSERT INTO " + tabName + "(";
          int colHeadCounter = 0;
          int colHeadLast = dt.Columns.Count;
          foreach ( DataColumn colHead in dt.Columns ) {
            string dType = colHead.DataType.ToString().ToLower().Substring( 7 );
            dTypesList.Add( dType );
            if ( ++colHeadCounter == colHeadLast ) {
              sqlCmd += colHead + " ";
            }
            else {
              sqlCmd += colHead + ", ";
            }
          }
          sqlCmd += ") VALUES(";
          //Console.Write( sqlCmd );
          colHeadCounter = 0;
          colHeadLast = row.ItemArray.Length;
          foreach ( var item in row.ItemArray ) {
            var temp = item.ToString();
            if ( temp.Count() == 0 ) {
              if ( ++colHeadCounter == colHeadLast ) {
                sqlCmd += ( "null " );
              }else {
                sqlCmd += ( "null, " );
              }
            }else if ( dTypesList[dTypesListIndexCounter] == "string"
             || dTypesList[dTypesListIndexCounter] == "char"
             || dTypesList[dTypesListIndexCounter] == "datetime"
             || dTypesList[dTypesListIndexCounter] == "single"
             || dTypesList[dTypesListIndexCounter] == "guid" ) {
              if ( ++colHeadCounter == colHeadLast ) {
                sqlCmd += ( "'" + item + "' " );
              }else {
                sqlCmd += ( "'" + item + "', " );
              }
            }else {
              if ( ++colHeadCounter == colHeadLast ) {
                sqlCmd += ( item + " " );
              }else {
                sqlCmd += ( item + ", " );
              }
            }
            dTypesListIndexCounter++;
          }
          sqlCmd += ")";
          //Console.Write( sqlCmd );
          //Console.WriteLine();
          SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand( sqlCmd, destConn );
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(cmd);
      Console.WriteLine( "Data copy executed." );
    }
    private static void DeleteTable( string tableName, SqlCeConnection pathConn) {
        string sqlCmd = "DROP TABLE " + tableName;
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand( sqlCmd, pathConn );
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine( tableName + " deleted." );
    }
    private static void CopyTableSchema( string tableName, DataTable dt, SqlCeConnection destConn ) {
        string sqlCmd = "Create table " + tableName + "(";
        int colHeadCounter = 0;
        int colHeadLast = dt.Columns.Count;
        /*sqlce supported types: bigint, integer,smallint,tinyint,bit,numeric, money, float, real, datetime,
         * national character, national character varying, ntext, nchar, binary,varbinary, image, uniqueidentifier,
         * identity, rowguidcol, timestamp/rowversion */
        foreach ( DataColumn colHead in dt.Columns ) {
          string dType = colHead.DataType.ToString().ToLower().Substring( 7 );

          ////still needs all type conversions mapped
          if ( dType == "int16" ) {
            dType = "smallint";
          }
          else if ( dType == "int32" ) {
            dType = "int";
          }
          else if ( dType == "int64" ) {
            dType = "bigint";
          }
          else if ( dType == "string" ) {
            dType = "nvarchar(4000)";
          }
          else if ( dType == "boolean" ) {
            dType = "bit";
          }
          else if ( dType == "byte" ) {
            dType = "tinyint";
          }
          else if ( dType == "byte[]" ) {
            dType = "binary";
          }
          else if ( dType == "char" ) {
            dType = "nchar";
          }
          else if ( dType == "datetime" ) {
            dType = "datetime";
          }
          else if ( dType == "decimal" ) {
            dType = "money";
          }
          else if ( dType == "double" ) {
            dType = "float";
          }
          else if ( dType == "sbyte" ) {
            dType = "tinyint";
          }
          else if ( dType == "single" ) {
            dType = "real";
          }
          else if ( dType == "guid" ) {
            dType = "uniqueidentifier";
          }
          else {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine( "Add new type to type conversion" );
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit( 0 );
          }

          if ( ++colHeadCounter == colHeadLast ) {
            sqlCmd += colHead + " " + dType;
          }
          else {
            sqlCmd += colHead + " " + dType + ", ";
          }
        }
        sqlCmd += ")";
        //Console.WriteLine( sqlCmd );
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand( sqlCmd, destConn );
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine( "Copy of " + tableName + " created." );
    }
    private static DataTable GetDataFromTable( string tableName, SqlCeConnection sourceConn ) {
      SqlCeCommand sourceCmd = sourceConn.CreateCommand();
      sourceCmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + tableName;
      SqlCeDataAdapter sourceAdp = new SqlCeDataAdapter( sourceCmd );
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      sourceAdp.Fill( dt );
      //Console.WriteLine( "The SqlCeDataAdapter succesfully filled " + dt.Rows.Count + " rows in the DataSet!" );
      return dt;
    }
    private static bool DoesTableExist(string tableName, SqlCeConnection destConn) {
      bool doesIt = false;
      SqlCeCommand destCmd = destConn.CreateCommand();
      destCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      destCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      destCmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM Information_Schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName";
      destCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "tableName", tableName );
      object result = destCmd.ExecuteScalar();
      if ( result != null ) {
        doesIt = true;
      }
      return doesIt;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did have to go back and add some code to deal with single quotations in the datum strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox in Visual Studio (or command line) to script the schema and table from one sdf file and also run the script against the other sdf file